# Explicitly return text "NULL" in MySQL query when result is NULL

Tags: mysql, database, sql, query

How would I write a SQL query in a MySQL environment where I explicitly replace all NULL values returned my query with the word NULL?

Comment: Or, don't... http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20160325-the-names-that-break-computer-systems

Comment: This is a terrible idea... a zero-length string might be somewhat acceptable, but the correct solution is to handle NULLs properly in your application.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT COALESCE( yourNullValue , 'NULL') FROM whatever`

> `COALESCE(value,...)`
>
> Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no
>   non-NULL values.
>
> The return type of COALESCE() is the aggregated type of the argument types.
>
> Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Comment: Functional, but please include a note indicating how much of a bad idea this is.